# How to use Spring Security username in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-security, jstl, dojo

I am trying to access the Spring Source Security user variable ${username} in some JavaScript and it keeps coming back as an empty string.  On a previous page, I am displaying the username with simply ${username}.  From all I can tell, all I need to do to get this in the javascript is:

```
<c:out value="${username}"/>
```

But in the code below, the generated HTML always has an empty string.  What am I missing?

```
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>The Admin Page</title>
<style type="text/css">

    .wideCols .field-radio { width: 5%; }
    .wideCols .field-username { width: 15%; }
    .wideCols .field-firstName { width: 15%; }
    .wideCols .field-lastName { width: 20%; }
    .wideCols .field-email { width: 40%; }
    .wideCols .field-enabled { width: 5%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Users</h1>
    <spring:url value="/admin/addUser" var="accountUrl" />

    <a href="${accountUrl}">Add User</a> 
    <div id="result1"></div>

    <div id="grid" class="wideCols"></div>
    <!-- <button type="button" id="saveNode"></button>  -->


    <script type="text/javascript">
        require([ "dojo/store/JsonRest",
                  "dojo/_base/declare",
                  "dgrid/OnDemandGrid",
                  "dgrid/Selection", 
                  "dgrid/editor",
                  "dgrid/selector",
                  "dojo/domReady!" 
                ], function(JsonRest, declare, OnDemandGrid, Selection, editor, selector) {

            var userAccountStore = new JsonRest({
                idProperty : "userAccountId",
                target : "<c:url value="/userMgr/" />"
            });

            window.grid = new (declare([OnDemandGrid, Selection]))({                
                store : userAccountStore,           
                columns:  [ selector({ label: 'radio'}, "radio"),
                            { label: "Username", field: "username"}, 
                            { label: "First Name", field: "firstName"}, 
                            { label: "Last Name", field: "lastName"}, 
                            { label: "Email", field: "email"}, 
                            editor({ label: "Enabled", field: "enabled", autoSave: "true", canEdit: function(object){
                                return object.username != "<c:out value="${username}"/>";
                            }, }, "checkbox")],
            }, "grid"); 

        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The username isn't automatically added to your model. You need to do that in the controller, or you can use a deprecated method in the Spring Security taglib if you don't have access to the controller code.:

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.username" />
```

See http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html#d0e6295 for more info.

Comment: Optionally use var attribute as <sec:authentication property="principal.username" var="username" /> to use <c:out value="${username}"/>